# input encoding in shiny app

Tags: regex, r, shiny-server, shiny

I am facing a problem in my shiny web app

First i will explain my web app

UI.R contain a text field and a send button
when the user enters a word, the server side is going to take that word and try to  get only the rows that contain this word from a datafram, then do some computation on this subset.

```
    fullData <- read.csv("C:/Documents/Data.csv", header= FALSE)
    subsetdata <- subset(fullData,grepl(word,  fullData$Sentences))
```

but i am facing an error that says:

> Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)

my inerface accepts Arabic Langauge which is a non ASCII charachter
i tried to use ICONV() to convert the entered word but i got the same error

i have tried the same code without shiny app i mean like normal function and it did work

Comment: Add `fixed = TRUE`: `grepl(word,  fullData$Sentences, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: where should i add it?

Comment: it still not working, do you have any idea that can help me?

Comment: If the literal entered has regex metachars in it you will get some error, but don't know what the _word_ is. Can you capture the _word_ and post it here ? The `U_` part might be related to Unicode.

Comment: i did not understand what do you mean, can you explain more?